# Want to get value from Select Tag by Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser()
    {
    //var s=document.getElementById('uni');     //this also not working
    //var str=s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    var str=document.form.formList.value;
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form  name="form">
    <select name="formList" id="uni" >
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">University 1</option>
    <option value="2">University 2</option>
    <option value="3">University 3</option>
    <option value="4">University 4</option>
    </select>
    <input  type="submit" value="Search" onsubmit="showUser()" >
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
    </body>
    </html>

 Want to get value from Select Tag by Submit button.....
```

By using javascript and then send to AJAX to forward that data to userget.php file to fetch data from SQL DATABASE and 
then show to on web.
please i'm stuck here anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong... ???
I want to to store value from drop down list by submit button...

/////////////////Server side code///////////////////////////

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','degree');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM uni WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Univeristy</th>
<th>Degree</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Fees</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";               
  echo "<td>" . $row['Id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Univeristy'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Degree'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Rank'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fees'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What is currently happening? What exactly do you want?

Comment: DATABASE not returning the values base on selected value on dropdown list..

Comment: @user2682833 show your server side code

Comment: @user2682833 did you try adding `/` before `getuser.php`?

Comment: @user2682833 and where is `return false;` after `showUser` invocation in `onsubmit`? Your form is being submitted with no ajax request ever sent to the server. You have too much mistakes here, consider using `jQuery` for a start, it makes such things less painful, especially for beginners.

Comment: Move the submit listener from the input to the form. Input elements don't receive submit events, forms do.

Comment: Putting the user id straight into the mysql string like that is a horrible idea for security

Comment: @ArseniuszŁozicki i'm just a beginner... i have to do this by using js ,Ajax and php...

Comment: @Max i need solution for beginner ... have no concern with security...

Comment: the code works fine by using Onchange(); function in the SELECT tag but i want to use submit button ... what i have to do for this  ????

Comment: change it from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and see how it goes.

Comment: @user2682833 move onsubmit to a form tag, thats quite simple even for a beginner; it is one of the basic things in HTML/JS

Comment: @ArseniuszŁozicki then how to get value from options and send to AJAX file in my case..???

Comment: @user2682833 Oh yeah change it from `onsubmit` to `onclick`.

Comment: @Deryck without event being prevented, form will be submitted and `XMLHttpRequest` will never be executed/succeded.

Comment: @ArseniuszŁozicki I know, that's why i said to change it from `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` and from `onsubmit="` to `onclick="`

Comment: @Deryck thanx buddy ... it works.. without using JQuery:D

Comment: Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/DPK4N/2/)

Comment: @user2682833 no problem.  it's in an answer for ya down below.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery, you may do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchButton').click(function(){
        if ($('#uni').val()) {
            $.post(
                'getuser.php',
                {
                    q: $('#uni').val()        
                },
                function(personInfo){
                    if (personInfo) {
                        $('#txtHint').text(personInfo)
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert('Please select an option first.');
        }     
    });
});
```

Just change the input type in your form from submit to button and add the id as "searchButton".

In your server side script, use POST instead of GET:

```
$q = intval($_POST['q']);
```

Comment: He wants to do it the hard way. No `jQuery`, no googling, just    plain old javascipt

Answer (score 0):

First of all more reliable method of getting  `xmlhttp`

```
function getXmlHttp(){ 
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}
```

Second is that correct form to do what you want is that:

```
<form  name="form" onsubmit="showUser(); return false;">
  <select name="formList" id="uni" >
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">University 1</option>
    <option value="2">University 2</option>
    <option value="3">University 3</option>
    <option value="4">University 4</option>
  </select>
  <input  type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

And showUser function like that:

```
function showUser()
{
  //var s=document.getElementById('uni');     //this also not working
  //var str=s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  var str=document.form.formList.value;

  if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }

  var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      } else {
        // add error handler here
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to bother with `submit` at all.  This will do the trick :)

```
<input type="button" onclick="showUser();" value="Search" />
```